# Is this conjecture about the binomial and beta distributions true?

Tags: pr.probability, probability-distributions, inequalities, asymptotics

Let $X$ follow a binomial distribution with parameters $n$ and $p$, and also fix $k$ such that $1<k<n$. Define

$$a = \mathbb{E}(X-k)^+$$
and
$$b = \mathbb{E}\log\binom{X}{(X-k)^+}$$
where the notation is $(t)^+=\max\{t,0\}$.  I claim that $$3\sqrt{ap}\exp\left(\frac{b}{-2a}\right) \geq \sqrt{n} \int_0^p \sqrt{F_{k,n-k}(t)} dt  $$ where $F_{k,n-k}(t)$ is the CDF for a beta distribution with parameters $\alpha=k$ and $\beta=n-k$.  Do I have any hope of proving this?  I believe it is true because of numerical simulations using the MATLAB code below:

```
n = 40; k = 25; %some arbitrarily chosen values
P = linspace(0,1);
f = @(x) sqrt(n*betacdf(x,k,n-k));
for i = 1:length(P)
    p = binopdf(0:n,n,P(i));
    q = p.*((0:n)-k);
    q = q(q>0); a = sum(q);
    b = 0;
    for j = k:n
        b = b + p(j+1)*log(nchoosek(j, j-k));
    end
    LHS(i) = 3*sqrt(a*P(i))*exp(-1/2*b/a);
    RHS(i) = integral(f,0,P(i));
end
plot(P,LHS./RHS); title('Conjecture is true if this plot is always >1');
```